# Drawing a sample from complex survey design in R

Tags: r, sampling, survey

I'm using R 'Survey' package to analyze public data from a National Health Survey. One step in my analysis requieres to draw a Monte Carlo sample from that survey. I noticed there’s no `svysample` function in the Survey package. So I was wondering if I should just proceed with something like this:

```
MySample <- sample(1:nrow(SurveyData), 10000, replace = T)
```

Else, if complex survey design needs to be accounted for, how do I do that in R?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: could you add some link to the "missing" function `svysample`? Without that context it might be difficult to answer your question. Also, perhaps [this code example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sampling-for-monte-carlo-simulations-with-r/) helps you with a MC sampling function

Comment: I am not sure the function is missing. I just want to draw a random sample with replacement that accounts for the complex survey design of my data. I was expecting such function to be in the Survey package, but there isn't. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a random sample with replacement that accounts for the complex survey design. For example, one use of random sampling with replacement is the bootstrap, and this has been extended to complex sampling in multiple different ways

Comment: Thanks for replying @ThomasLumley and sorry for being unclear. In this case, my desired final result would be a dataframe object of n = 10,000. Something that in other circumstances would be achieved simply by doing: `i <- sample(1:nrow(original.df), 10000, replace = T)` followed by `new.df <- original.df[i,]`. However, my data here has a complex survey design, so I believe that won't work. I assume that I need to account for the complex survey design somehow, the problem is don't know how. Hope this further clarifies my question.

Comment: @ThomasLumley, can you give some examples of R functions that can be used to take a bootstrap resample of complex survey data, such as the NSFG?

Comment: The function `as.svrepdesign()` in the survey package constructs replicate weights, including three types of bootstrap.

Comment: @GabrielConzuelo It's still not clear what properties you want this sample to have that are accounting for the complex sampling.